# How do I use CSS in ion-list, ion-item

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am developing an app and I am getting data from JSON and it works well, but my problem is that I don't know how to use CSS style using the directive. Below I am showing the code. The second code is the code that the css works.

```
<!-- With Json </!-->

<ion-list>  
    <ion-item>

       <a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'Name'"  href="#">
          <img ng-src="{{x.Image}}">
          <h2>{{x.Name}}</h2>
          <p>  {{x.Local}}</p>
        </a>

    </ion-item>
</ion-list> 


<!-- example static, without json, css works good  </!--> 
<div class="list" id="inicioPalestrantes" >
   <a class="item item-avatar" id="palestrantes" href="#">
     <img src="Fiona.jpg">
     <h2>Fiona Doohan</h2>
     <p> UDC, Dublin, Ireland </p>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: In your latter example you provide an ID on your < a > attribute, but not on your first example... Could you provide the css?

Comment: yes, i had tried use id but it doesn't worked.

Comment: Post your css please, we can't help without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You <strike>need the id selector `#`</strike> better use the `class` instead of `id` for your CSS rules.

```
.list .item {
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.list {
  margin-top:0%;
}
```

Comment: @Sobucki I see, doesn't this work? .. or your answer you deleted was a self answer which works, but you was just not able to post it correct?

Comment: No, my css there are the '#', but when I use in <a id.. or in ion-item it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sobucki Okay, do you have more than 1 item in the list? .. and have all the same id?

Comment: Yes, in the JSON there are more itens and there are the same id

Comment: @Sobucki Using same id many times is invalid. I updated my answer with `#inicioPalestrantes a {...}`. Will that work?

Comment: Didn't work @LGSon, I had used id="inicioPalestrantes", I don't know if change the call with the 'a' you had put in the css.

Comment: @Sobucki I updated once more, using the class name instead. Will that work for you?

Comment: work man, thank you so much, I am my TCC from garduate, thanks a lot.